What is the difference between $ L_e$ and $E_{TM} $?
What is the difference between $L_e = \{ \langle M \rangle | L(M) = \emptyset \}$  and
$E_{TM} = \{ \langle M \rangle | \text{M is a turing machine and L(M)} = \emptyset \}$?
$L_e$ is not RE and $E_{TM}$ is undecidable but they seem like the same language to me.

Why do you think they are different?  What is the intended meaning of $L_e$?  Where did you encounter it?  What would $L(M)$ mean if $M$ is not a Turing machine?

@D.W. They look the same to me but I don't understand how $L_e$, seen in Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation, is not RE but $E_{TM}$, in Introduction to the Theory of Computation, is undecidable.

Every language that is not RE is also undecidable, so both can be true.
